# lxml xpath select element do not work like jquery

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a page as below:

```
<div class="coupon_table" style="margin:10px 0px;">
    <div class="grid" style="height: 330px; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
        <table class="grid_table" widtd="100%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td style="widtd:20px">eee</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">fff</td>
                    <td style="widtd:90px">www</td>
                    <td style="widtd:90px">rrr</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">sss</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">vvvv</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class ="tt">
                    <td style="widtd:20px">eee</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">fff</td>
                    <td style="widtd:90px">www</td>
                    <td style="widtd:90px">rrr</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">sss</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">vvvv</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class ="tt">
                    <td style="widtd:20px">eee</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">fff</td>
                    <td style="widtd:90px">www</td>
                    <td style="widtd:90px">rrr</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">sss</td>
                    <td style="widtd:80px">vvvv</td>
                </tr>
                ....
                ....
                ....
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to get all tr which have class `tt`.
So I write something like:

```
p = html.document_fromstring(r.text)
for row in p.xpath('/div/div/table/tr[@class="tt"]')
     proxy.ip =  row.xpath('/td[1]')[0].text_content() 
     proxy.port = row.xpath('/td[2]')[0].text_content() 
     .....
```

But `row.xpath('/td[1]')` doesn't start searching at`/div/div/table/tr[@class="tt"]`,it find nothing.
Simply to explain,`len(row.xpath('//td')) ==  len(p.xpath('//td'))` is True.
if I use jquery , `row = $('.tt').firts()` ,and `row.find('td')`  find will start search element at every tr which have class `tt`

How can I achieve my purpose with lxml??

Comment: `/` is like jQuery's `.children()`. `//` is like `.find()`.

Comment: @Blender `row.xpath('/td[1]')` doesn't search start at `/div/div/table/tr[@class="tt"]`, that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `td[1]` instead of `/td[1]`:

```
for row in p.xpath('.//div/div/table//tr[@class="tt"]'):
    proxy.ip =  row.xpath('td[1]')[0].text_content()
    proxy.port = row.xpath('td[2]')[0].text_content()
```

or

```
for row in p.xpath('.//div/div/table//tr[@class="tt"]'):
    proxy.ip =  row.find('td[1]').text_content()
    proxy.port = row.find('td[2]').text_content()
```

I also prepended `.//` to the first xpath to match any `div`. replaced `table/tr` with `table//tr` because `tr` is inside `tbody` tag.

Alternatively you can use `cssselect`:

```
for row in p.cssselect('div>div>table tr.tt'):
    proxy.ip =  row.cssselect('td:nth-child(1)')[0].text_content() 
    proxy.port = row.cssselect('td:nth-child(2)')[0].text_content()
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! But I can't replaced `table/tr` with `table//tr`.Because `table/tbody/tr` find nothing while `table/tr ` works in lxml.I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe you are seeing not the real html output, but the output of some kind of browser's dom content.

Comment: Oh,I get it.It is chrome who adds the tbody which doesn't find in the source html.